# MySql: select rows between two specific values:

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

[image]

and I'd like to select the rows between 'inizio_votazione1' e fine_votazione1'.

I tried this code:

```
$sql  = "SELECT codice FROM scansioni WHERE codice BETWEEN 'inizio_votazione1' 
AND 'fine_votazione1'";

while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
// print_r($row);

$res = $row[0];
echo $res;
echo "<br />";
}
```

but I see no result.

Which is the correct syntax to retrieve the desired result?
Thanks

Comment: how dynamic does this have to be? If it is always those records you want I would run a between on your id field instead: `WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 9`

Comment: do you want all rows between these value?

Comment: It's dynamic because are runtime votes, so I thought to find the way to mark each votation inserting a record with "inizio('begin')" and "fine('end')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really want to use `BETWEEN`. That will basically look for alphabetically ordered values that are between those two. I would think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT codice
FROM scansioni
WHERE id > (SELECT MIN(id) 
            FROM scansioni
            WHERE codice IN ('inizio_votazione1', 'fine_votazione1'))
  AND id < (SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM scansioni
            WHERE codice IN ('inizio_votazione1', 'fine_votazione1'))
```

This may not be the most elegant solution, but from what I tried, it worked.

A better option might be to add a separate table that stores the start and end `id` for each group. Then you could just get the start and end `id`s for the group you want and then select all the values from scansioni that have `id`s in the correct range.

Comment: You are right. I hadn't tried the solution in MySQL. I just changed my answer so that it should work for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT codice FROM scansioni WHERE codice between 'inizio_votazione1' abd 'fine_votazione1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$sql  = SELECT codice FROM scansioni WHERE codice BETWEEN 'inizio_votazione1' 
AND 'fine_votazione1';
```

To:

```
$sql  = "SELECT codice FROM scansioni WHERE codice BETWEEN 'fine_votazione1' 
AND 'inizio_votazione1'";
```

BETWEEN uses the sort order to determine the result.

Also, strings need to be quoted in php.

Comment: You're right, but I just mistyped when I wrote the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT codice FROM `scansioni` WHERE id between (select id from scansioni where codice='inizio_votazione1') and (select id from scansioni where codice='fine_votazione1')
```